# Rails link a tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the code below and I want to create an  tag between the div with the class 'box'.
I cant just use the link_to method because I want this link to encompass all the html code  from the  to its respective ending .  So anyone who clicks within that box gets transported to the equivalent of: <%= link_to( 'go', { action: :edit, id: course.id }) %>.  I tried finding this else where but failed.

```
<% @courses.in_groups_of(3, false) do |group| %>  <!--Takes groups of three courses -->
<div class="row">
  <% group.each do |course| %>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="image"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn-lg white"></span></div>
        <div class="info">
          <h3 class="title"><%= course.name %> | GPA: <%= course.gpa.to_f %></h3>
          <p>
            <%= course.description %>
          </p>
          <div class="more">
            <a href="#" title="Title Link"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Details
            </a>
            <%= link_to( 'go', { action: :edit, id: course.id }) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="space"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to({ action: :edit, id: course.id  }) do %>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icon">
      <div class="image"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn-lg white"></span></div>
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title"><%= course.name %> | GPA: <%= course.gpa.to_f %></h3>
        <p>
          <%= course.description %>
        </p>
        <div class="more">
          <a href="#" title="Title Link"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think you are asking to enclose your html code into a link_to tag. So try this:

```
<%= link_to path_to_land_on do %>
  <div class='box'>
    // other code
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Replace `path_to_land_on` with `{ action: :edit, id: 2 }` or path